# using getClass().getResource gives null pointer exception in command line, but works fine in gradle or Intellij

Tags: java, user-interface, gradle, command-line-interface

```
    theDeck.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Cards-1.png")));
```

Above is code that i set an icon of a jlabel. 
[The program structure is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb4yU.png)

My question is when I try to run the program using command line, it will give me a nullpointer exception. But if i run the same problem using intellij IDE or gradle, it works fine. What is the reason here?

[This is the exception that it throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayM7a.png)

```
   System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/").getPath());
```

I tried to figure out the root directory of the image when running gradle, and it shows me it is in (something)/build/classes/java/main/. I think my main question is why changing the classpath will solve the problem? My image is not in the path, how does the program find the image?

Comment: So what's null? Is `getClass().getResource(...)` returning null, or is that throwing? You've got a *lot* going on for a single line of code that's throwing - separate it into tiny stages.

Comment: Do you run the whole JAR or just a class? Also, it is usually better to use some ClassLoader that is not tied to the current class, the java resources are a bit mind-bending and I guess it's easier to just centralize the resource management for the project.

Comment: I updated the exception I got when running only the class. I think it's becuase the getResource cannot get the image, so it returns null. The imageicon didn't receive any source so it throws nullerpointer exception. That's doesn't seem to happen when I try with gradle build and gradle run.